# why the image can't find in iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, image, barcode, simulator

I want to test a BarCode demo, But I haven't got an Iphone. so I must test the image of BarCode in the simulator.

I drag the image of BarCode on the simulator. And pressed the picture for a while and save it.

but I test the below code. I can't find any picture above.

```
ZBarReaderController *reader = [ZBarReaderController new];

reader.readerDelegate = self;

if([ZBarReaderController isSourceTypeAvailable:
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    reader.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                      config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                          to: 0];
[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];
```

I have dealt with the problem for a day, but I haven't been able to find why...

Hope I can solve it in the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue with the simulator. I once made it work by saving images twice.

Comment: that is all .thank you for response.

the reason is   after we pressed the save button We still press the return Button of Iphone.

it will really save it .

Answer (score 0):

I had this numerous times. I believe the trick is to open the images app prior to saving the image. Then close it, switch to Safari and save the image.

Comment: i find  the reason. after we save it ,We should pressed the retrun button of Iphone to make it effet.

Comment: that is all .thank you for response.

the reason is   after we pressed the save button We still press the return Button of Iphone.

it will really save it .